# Changing X.org default font

Tags: linux, fonts, xorg, arch-linux

Installed ArchLinux, run X server, i3wm and some gtk+ applications (chromium, gedit etc.). Applications use font which is the same as my virtual console's font (Terminus I guess). How to switch to different font? I've read articles and came to conclusion that there some contemporary and some deprecated ways to do this. What is the most up-to-date one?